# How can I find previous usages of a variable using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis, roslyn

I'm writing a Rosyln analyser/analyzer.  It checks to ensure that a method is called before accessing another (potentially dangerous) method on a type.  To show what I mean, here's some bad code that I want to analyse and fail on:

```
private void myMethod()
{
    var myThing = new MyThing();
    myThing.Value = null;

    string value = myThing.GetValue(); // code blows up here as the internal value is null
}
```

Here's code that's OK because it calls a method that says whether it's null:

```
private void myMethod()
{
    var myThing = new MyThing();
    myThing.Value = null;

    if(!myThing.HasValue)
    {
        return ;
    }

    string value = myThing.GetValue(); 
}
```

So, it should check that all calls to `GetValue` are preceeded by a call to `HasValue`.

I've just started with Roslyn, so there's probably a more elegant way than my initial (failing) attempt at:

1 - Declare that I want to inspect invocation expressions

```
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(analyseMemberAccessNode, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
```

2 - In my method, I get the method name (`GetValue()`)

```
var expr = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

var memberAccess = expr.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;

if (memberAccess?.Name.ToString() != "GetValue")
    return;
```

3 - I then check to see if it's the right 'GetValue'

```
var memberSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memberAccess).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;

if (!memberSymbol?.OverriddenMethod.ToString().StartsWith("MyNamespace.MyThing.GetValue") ?? true)
    return;
```

4 - Up to here, everything is fine.  So I get the name of the *variable*

```
var e = memberAccess.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax;

string variableName = e.Identifier.Text;
```

5 - **now I'm stuck** - my theory was to; get the containing method, find the single variable declaration that matches `variableName`, find usages of that, and ensure that `HasValue` is called before `GetValue`.

In short, using a Roslyn analyser (deriving from `DiagnosticAnalyzer`), how do I ensure that `HasValue` is called before `GetValue`?

Comment: You're looking for `DataFlow`.  http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Extensions.cs,168

Answer (score 3):

Instead of registering for each Invocation, you might be better off registering for the entire method declaration.  Then you can keep track of all `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` and ensure that for a given variable that `HasValue` is called before `GetValue`.  To do that, I would get the `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` descendants from the `MethodDeclaration` node.

```
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction((analysisContext) =>
{
    var invocations =
        analysisContext.Node.DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>();
    var hasValueCalls = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var invocation in invocations)
    {
        var e = invocation.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax;

        if (e == null)
            continue;

        string variableName = e.Identifier.Text;

        if (invocation.Name.ToString() == "HasValue")
        {
            hasValueCalls.Add(variableName);
        }

        if (invocation.Name.ToString() == "GetValue")
        {
            if (!hasValueCalls.Contains(variableName))
            {
                analysisContext.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, e.GetLocation()));
            }
        }
    }
}, SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration);
```